# php replace ' in string

Tags: php, replace

Consider this `href='123.html'` I'd like replace ' to get `href="123.html"`, thus replacing ' with ".

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
echo str_replace("\'", "\"", "href='123.html'");
```

How would one do this in php?

Comment: have you tried echo str_replace("'", "\"", "href='123.html'"); ?

Answer (score 10):

The `'` MUST NOT being escaped when enclosed in double quotes. This will work:

```
echo str_replace("'", "\"", "href='123.html'");
```

Comment: Or, this `echo str_replace("'",'"',"href='123.html'");`

Comment: As Burhan said, you could use single-quotes instead to avoid having to escape the quotes. +1 though!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("'",'"',"href='1234'");
```

Works fine on PHP 5.3.15

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the single quote, when the string is set within double quotes

```
echo str_replace("'", "\"", "href='123.html'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to escape the `'`.

```
echo str_replace("'", '"', "href='123.html'");
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/8YIhjGFj)